# 403 Forbidden error using Subversion

Tags: svn

I recently upgraded to Subversion 1.5, and now I cannot commit my code to the repository. I get an error message: "403 Forbidden in response to MKACTIVITY". I know the upgrade worked because my fellow developers are not getting this issue. What's going on?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Apparently my SVN URL had the wrong case! A Google search turned up an article (no longer available online) that explained what was going on. My URL was of the form http://svn.foobar.com/foobar but the actual repository was called http://svn.foobar.com/fooBar.

I use TortoiseSVN, so the fix was to use the Relocate command to correct the path to the repository.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks Todd.  The link you have for "this article" doesn't seem to actually lead to the article.  Try this: http://blog.alagad.com/2007/11/12/subversion-mkactivity-and-403-forbidden-headaches/

Comment: Todd, also meant to ask if you could post steps for reproducing the problem.  Though our developers seem to have this problem occasionally, I am unable to reproduce it myself.

Comment: I have never been able to reproduce it consistently, but the fix works every time. As mentioned below, it is related to Windows' tendency to accept both case types where Subversion is more picky.

Comment: Would not the correct-case version of the URL be the one that is returned by the `svn info` command (URL: line)?  I'm having the same error, but copy/pasted the path from `svn info`.  Any other hints?

Answer (score 6):

We run into the periodically and it is very frustrating to developers.  For some reason reading from the repository seems to be case insensitive but commit cares.

I understand the reason why case matters due to Subversion's roots in unix filing systems that are case sensitive, but I really wish you would get the error on the initial checkout not on the commit!

Comment: Agree, getting the error doing checkout would be much better.

Answer (score 2):

Another instance when this issue will rear its head is if you commit a file twice with the same name but with different capitalizations (e.g., foobar and FooBar).  This is only possible, of course, on a windows system and may just be a special case of Todd's answer above.  One of our developers accidentally did this and it similarly cost us many debugging hours.

Answer (score 2):

Todd is right. The stupid thing is that the repo browser accepts upper- and lowercase when checking out but the commit will fail if you used the wrong case when checking out.

I checked out from https://svn.domain.com/Company/Product/trunk but couldn't commit because the correct URL was https://svn.domain.com/company/product/trunk.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason, within a msWin environment as client, are the proxy settings.

Configuration: *internet-explorer/internetOptions/connections/LAN-Settings/advanced/exceptions*

Put your SVN-Server within the exceptions.

Names may be others, I do not use english as sys language.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Access to 'foo' forbidden` or `403 Forbidden` indicates that your user account lacks permissions to the requested repository. As repository names and paths in repositories are case-sensitive, you should *check that the URL you entered is correct* and that you log on under correct credentials. Run [`svn auth`](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-auth) to view stored credentials on your client computer.

Normally, access control in Subversion is implemented in form of [path-based authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) and fully supports **Read / Write**, **Read Only** and **No Access** access levels. If you implement a complex access control policy, you must understand the access control principles in Subversion. Read the article [KB33: Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) for more information. While it says 'VisualSVN Server' in title, the article covers path-based authorization in general and should apply to other SVN server distributions.

Comment: This was my issue. I was granted **Read Only** access, then when trying to commit I received the *403 Forbidden* error. Talked to admin to grant me **Read / Write** access and I was able to commit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried several answers provided above, but none worked for me. I found out that I had two versions of eclipse installed and subversion was installed on the previous version of eclipse. I've done the below steps to resolve the 403-forbidden-error:

- delete the subversion folder \AppData\Roaming\Subversion
- uninstall subversion from eclipse
- installed subversion

Answer (score 1):

I had credentials that were no longer used, but they were recorded in the settings.

It was enough to remove these old settings that my problem was solved.

Open **Settings** of **Tortoise SVN**:

1. Saved Data

   - Authentication data

     - Clear all
2. Refresh repository
3. Login again with right credencials

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing here is that Subversion (regardless of OS platform its server is installed on) **is** case sensitive.

However, clients' OS maybe not. And that might create a problem.

In my company I have had this case and it took me about an hour to figure it out. So, one developer, who was working on mac, committed to svn file with the same name, but he changed couple of letters in its name to capital ones. For mac and subversion it is not a problem and file got in.

Later another developer, who happened to work on windows laptop got an error and windows got completely confused and could not do anything.

so, the solution was - I asked developers, which of two files I can delete. I did it on linux and everybody happy ever since.

so, upper/low case spelling is not a subversion problem, but windows OS one.

Answer (score 0):

It happened for me and the reason being i do not have access to that folder. Once admin added my user, i was able to checkout the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

> an error occurred while accessing the repository entry(403 Forbidden)

and i found a few different approaches. But for me the solution was: download the correct plugin (`subclipse 1.4`) version for `svn` installed on server which was `1.4.3`

Comment: Could you please explain more how you installed this feature?

Comment: i just installed subclipse from http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.4.x

since the svn version at server is 1.4.3

in eclipse svn repository exploring i added my repository path, eg. 
https://myserver/svn/myproject/trunk

Answer (score 0):

The user/certificate has no privileges to read the repo in svn. For that reason, you can not access the repository through the browser / tortoise.
Talk with the admin to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that, Jenkins was going through a proxy. I had given below properties in catalina.properties file of Tomcat.

```
http.proxyHost=proxyserver
http.proxyPort=3128
```

In order to instruct it to avoid going through proxy I had to add http.nonProxyHosts property. Multiple hosts can be seperated by pipe (|)

```
http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|*.companydomain.com
```

SVN server was on the intranet. I didn't need to go through proxy.

Answer (score 0):

For me, update was working but the commit operation was giving me 403 forbidden error. I got this fixed when I did the email verification.