# svn: MKACTIVITY 403 Forbidden

Tags: svn

I´m getting this error while trying to commit to a svn repository:

```
svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/Demo/!svn/act/e2e65cfa-...4165f': 403 Forbidden (http://svn....com:8088)
```

Any idea why? I googled a lot, but cannot find a solution that works for me.

Comment: looks like a permissiosn problem

Comment: Yes, this error can occur when you only have read access to a repository

Comment: @PhilMY Thats not true.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check if you supplied the correct credentials or you have enought rights to reach that repo (usually looking at authz files, if you can manage the server config). As one commenter said above is a permission problem.

Comment: Got the problem after changed my Subersion password but not updated TortoiseSVN saved password. Post on how to change TortoiseSVN password: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034026/how-to-change-password-using-tortoisesvn

Comment: This didn't work for me. Im my case, it was a problem with the URL case as described in Stiefel's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3289512/1385405 and in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/a/57148/1385405

Answer (score 34):

I do not know if this answer helps you, but in my case it had something to do with server domain names and case sensitivity.

The URL we used for this working copy was

https://bhm18a.serona.org:8443/svn/nebeam/eco/branches/apple2010

instead of the correct URL

https://bhm18a:8443/svn/NeBeam/eco/branches/apple2010

Misteriously, the wrong URL worked for "check out" and "update" and browsing the respository but not for "copy" or "commit".

Checking out a new working copy using the exact URL made the problems disappear.

(Using subversion 1.6.12 with Visual SVN Server installed on a Microsoft Windows Server)

Answer (score 7):

Double check casing in repository path.

Answer (score 6):

I run across this issue all the time and

```
rm -rf ~/.subversion/auth
```

always works for me.

Delete this directory and then try to commit again.

Answer (score 5):

Case in the repository path MUST match the case on the server.  I spent many hours tracking down why some users could commit changes to the repository and others could not.  It turns out the initial checkout for the "forbidden" users was done with the URL in all lowercase "../svn/robotconfig" when the name of the repository was actually "../svn/RobotConfig".  After doing a fresh checkout with the properly cased repository name, users were able to commit changes.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the "solution" was: The stupid admin in our company simply changed everything from SVN to GIT without communicating this to the devs. Seriously.

Answer (score 4):

I've the same problem. I'm using Intellij, and I solved this problem by doing the following:

1. File --> Settings
2. Under "Version Control" List select "Subversion".
3. In General Tab you, find & Click on the "Clear Auth Cache".
4. Hit Ok.
5. Try to check-in some changes, and the Intellij will ask you about your credentials.

[image]

It seems this problem happened after you do `svn switch --relocate` command on your checked-out branch.

Enjoy!

Comment: Intellij version: 14.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if the user places a space at the end of their username. Our setup is svn via http in apache. If a user places whitespace at the end if their username, it will get trimmed and apache will pass the auth though. However svn will fail to find the username and you will get this rather cryptic error.

It can also happen due to an odd url case problem. Windows does not make a difference in filesystem case, but svn does (even when running on windows). See some info on this [here](http://www.alagad.com/blog/post.cfm/subversion-mkactivity-and-403-forbidden-headaches).

Answer (score 2):

Username case-sensitivity was the issue for me.   Administrator told me my username was ... "MyName" which worked for checkout and update but on commit, "myname" lowercase had to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 Forbidden error happened after I modified the .htaccess to limit request methods with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD|POST|PROPFIND|OPTIONS|PUT)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen to me using Eclipse with the Subversive plugin. Performing a Team>Cleanup on the project fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, the issue is with old credentials which are stored in the below folders 
`\Users\<Your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn`.Simple

Just took back up of files from this folder and delete all and try committing again, `SVN` or `Subclipse`will prompt username and password and provide it and done, it will commit.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my eclipse and started to get this very same problem.

I did all the tricks, nothing seems to work. But old eclipse still working.

So, I realized that someone in IT team had changed the domain name case, so my userId changed from:

DOMAIN\username to domain\username

So, after delete `\Users\<Your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`, sign in dialog show up again and back on track.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the root of the problem was not in casing but in changed svn port.

Fixed this with relocation of working copy:

```
svn switch --relocate https://svn.company.com/svn/path/branches/java8 https://svn.company.com:465/svn/path/branches/java8
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue when I was committing for the first time for a new svn branch, which was due to lower case used in the URL path when it should have been upper case at checkout time. In the .svn folder of the root checkout directory, find the file wc.db, open it in a text editor, do a global replace of the incorrect URL path with the correct URL path, save the file. Do commit again, you will not have that problem any more.