# How to change password using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, passwords, tortoisesvn

I need to change my SVN password.  I am using TortoiseSVN client.  I am not able to find the password change or add user option.

Is it possible?   Is there any work around or command line syntax to create an SVN user or edit users?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is just the client, it can't be used to manage passwords.  If you want to add/change/delete svn users you have to find your SVN SERVER program.  It could be any one of a number of available programs.  For me on Windows, the program is (http://www.visualsvn.com/) and can be found in Start->Programs->VisualSVN" and choose the option "VisualSVN Manager".  Left click the Users folder and right click the user to change the password.  Or choose Actions->Create User.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Password changes are handled by the subversion server administrator.  As a user there is no password change option.

Check with your server admin.

If you are the admin, find your SVN Server installation.  If you don't know where it is, it could be listed in Start->Programs, running under services in Start->Control Panel->Services or it could be listed under C:\Program Files.

The SVN Server should have an application to run to add/change/delete authentication and users.

Answer (score 101):

### To change your password for accessing Subversion

Typically this would be handled by your Subversion server administrator.  If that's you and  you are using the built-in authentication, then edit your `[repository]\conf\passwd` file on your Subversion server machine.

### To delete locally-cached credentials

Follow these steps:

- Right-click your desktop and select **TortoiseSVN->Settings**
- Select **Saved Data**.
- Click **Clear** against **Authentication Data**.

Next time you attempt an action that requires credentials you'll be asked for them.

If you're using the command-line `svn.exe` use the `--no-auth-cache` option so that you can specify alternate credentials without having them cached against your Windows user.

Comment: I think OP wants to change his password on the server side.

Comment: I did follow the same method. Somehow, Tortoise SVN doesn't ask my username/password. Strange. Do we have any Tortoise SVN reset settings? I am getting this error "Authorization Failed" while committing. I don't have any problem if I use same credentials from a different machine. Both machines have the latest Tortoise SVN installed. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change your password through TortoiseSVN.  Authentication to the SVN server has to be changed within the SVN server itself.

How you actually achieve this depends on which SVN Server is housing the repository and how the SVN Server was laid out on your computer.

n a Windows environment, credentials are typically stored in `<yoursvnroot>\conf\passwd`.

In a Linux environment it could be as above, or a myriad of other ways depending on how it's hosted.

Answer (score 2):

On the server.. In our environment, we're running Apache2 on Windows Server 2003.
Suppose Apache is serving our repository from C:\repo\MyProject

The actual repository is in C:\repo\MyProject\db

and the configuration is in C:\repo\MyProject\conf

So the passwords are in: C:\repo\MyProject.htaccess

They're encrypted, a tool similar to this: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line in htpasswd file:

go to: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator-windows/

(if the link is expired, search another generator from google.com)

Enter your username and password. The site will generate encrypted line. Copy that line and replace it with the previous line in the file "repo/htpasswd".

You might also need to 'clear' the 'Authentication data' from tortoisSVN -> settings -> saved data

Answer (score 1):

If your administrator changed your password, and Windows 10 still stores your old password you will not be asked for a new password. Windows 10 will use the stored old password, and authentication will fail.

You can delete your old password by

1. Click Start > Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage your credentials
2. Windows credentials
3. Modify or delete the stored password

After you deleted your password, next time, when you try to use SVN, you will be asked for the new password.

Answer (score 0):

I changed windows password today then Tortoise declined to connect me to SVN server.   I got around it by opening a Dos box and doing an "svn co ...".   It prompted for the new credential then happily did its work.   After that, Tortoise works also.