# Subversion commit failed - but my credentials are correct

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, subclipse

My problem is very similar to: [svn: MKACTIVITY 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032209/svn-mkactivity-403-forbidden)

My error message is as follows (the spacing is awkward, but that's how it looks in Eclipse):

```
    svn: Commit failed (details follow):
    svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svnroot/...': 403 Forbidden (https://repository.url)
```

#### My Software:

- Linux OS with KDE user interface,
- SpringSource Tool Suite version 2.9.1,
- Subclipse version 1.6.10

#### What I've tried:

1. Close Eclipse. Delete the .keyring file in the Eclipse's 'configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime' directory (to reset any stored credentials).
2. Modifying '/home/[user_name]/.subversion/servers' to have the password stored.

Comment: Check the owner of the `/svnroot/`.  I'm guess it has more to do with the file permissions then your svn credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that OnResolve (from the comments on the original post) was correct. I spoke to the owner of /svnroot/ and I needed to register an account before being able to commit.

Comment: Yes, it is just a matter of permission when you see 403 forbidden error anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, the issue is with old credentials which are stored in the below foldes \Users\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple

Just took back up of files from this folder and delete all and try committing again, SVN or Subclipse will prompt username and password and provide it and done, it will commit.