# While committing I get the following errors

Tags: tortoisesvn

When I try to commit, I get the following error. If any one faced this type of issue, please post workaround below.

> Command: Commit   Error: Commit failed (details follow):   Error:
>   Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to
>   MKACTIVITY    Error: request for
>   '/svn/!svn/act/3b83fce9-ef52-f148-8f08-f84f900e99dd'   Finished!:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svn: MKACTIVITY 403 Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032209/svn-mkactivity-403-forbidden)

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137/403-forbidden-error-using-subversion

Answer (score 2):

This error means that your credentials do not have write access to the path you're attempting to commit to. Subversion's path-based authorization rules are case-sensitive, but not all OSes that Subversion runs on are.

On servers where read access has been enabled for all users, it's quite common with Windows servers for people to check out from a URL that matches the spelling of the path (and the path is then found), but not the case (so the path isn't found in the authorization file). As a result, you can check out, but not commit.

Example:

You have checked out from `http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/Code/project1/TRUNK` but the URL is **actually** `http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/Code/Project1/trunk`. The authorization rule specifies `[Code:/Project1/trunk]` and as a result, it can't be matched and your commit is rejected.

You need to talk to your server admin to see if the URL you've checked out from (visible in the Properties dialog for your working copy, or via `svn info`) matches what the server expects.

Comment: That is the best answer I've seen so far for using the wrong case in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

> This problem is often about different permissions for different SVN
>   paths.
>
> If you get
>
> Commit failed (details follow): Server sent unexpected return value
>   (403 Forbidden) in response to MKACTIVITY request for
>   '/svn/reponame/your/path'
>
> First, try to write to another SVN path on the server. If that is also
>   not possible, admin maybe needs to check IP based restrictions, or
>   LDAP-based restrictions.
>
> In the case you cant write to that specific Dir,
>
> it is very likely your user has no write permission for the path
>   /svn/your/path. I.e. path based permissions configuration issue.
>
> Check:
>   1. Go to command line;
>   2. do svn ls svn://your.server/svn/reponame/your/path (the full URL of the path);
>   3. Enter credentials if needed. If you have no access, you user can’t even read the path
>   4. If you can list the path, user can read, but probably can’t write
>
> Next thing is to contact the SVN Admin. And for Admin is to check the
>   svnaccess privileges
>
> (See here
>   http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s04.html#svn-ch-6-sect-4.4.2)
>
> The reason you cannot read the path may be that the svnaccess file
>   which has restriction for your user or your group.
>
> [reponame:/some/path] SomeuserOrGroup = r
>
> Admin could probably test that by commenting out the line
>
> AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/access/file
>
> in httpd.conf

From: http://www.thinkplexx.com/blog/commit-failed-details-follow-server-sent-unexpected-return-value-403-forbidden-in-response-to-mkactivity-possible-reasons-what-to-do

If don't help you can look too:
http://www.kodkast.com/blogs/svn/server-sent-unexpected-return-value-403-forbidden-in-response-to-mkactivity-request

http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/37608-Server-sent-unexpected-return-value-%28403-Forbidden%29

[svn: MKACTIVITY 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032209/svn-mkactivity-403-forbidden)